# Converting JPG image to tiff file format

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a jpeg image to a tiff image, however unsuccessful in doing it using PHP. Kindly help me out with this issue.

The main thing is that the imagemagick and exec() system() and related commands are blocked by the my service provider.

So provide me solution which deosnt use imagick and command tools for conversion.

Comment: [Use GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and if that isn't available, search for a better host. GD is somewhat more commonly available on shared hosting services than ImageMagick PHP bindings, in my experience.

Comment: And to be clear, you have checked for the availability on your host of [the PHP ImageMagick bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) rather than trying to push it off to the CLI tools?

Comment: How do we do it using GD... I need a kind of help with the code.

Answer (score 0):

For this action you need to have Imagemagic installed on your server (it is installed by default on an average web server) after you have Imagemagic support do the following:

```
$command = "convert /path_to_file/filename.jpg /path_to_file/filename.tiff";
exec($command);
```

- if you dont have imagemagic install it from here:
  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: You missed the part about the service provider not permitting `exec()` calls.

Comment: uf, it sounds like I am to tired today. Got to get some sleep.